# Execute a method asynchronously using a WokManager

Tags: java, weblogic

My question is simple, how can I execute a method in java using the Weblogic WorkManager?
I don't want to use any Thread method of implementation.

Example:

```
public class CallerClass {

    public void callerMethod() {
        // Execution

        // Launch method in new thread
        obj.asyncMethod();

        // Continue before finishing ayncMethod
        return;
    }

    public void asyncMethod() {
        // Asynchronous method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps, i find it useful.
[using-the-weblogic-work-manager-to-delegate-long-running-tasks](http://www.virtual7.de/blog/2015/10/using-the-weblogic-work-manager-to-delegate-long-running-tasks/)